# cakephp3 load plugin for special prefix

Tags: cakephp, plugins, prefix

I have Cakephp 3 application and i want to load this plugin and the event listener below it just for admin prefix. ( not the entire project ) .

how can i achive this?

this is my

> config/bootstrap.php

where i load this plugin . (I load these at end of the file )

```
...

Plugin::load('Josegonzalez/Upload');

\Cake\Event\EventManager::instance()->on(new \App\Controller\Event\AppEventListener());
```

i want these to line only run on admin prefix

Answer (score 1):

You can't conditionally run code based upon *routing* inside *boostrap.php* as the routing configuration for you app hasn't been loaded yet.

You'll have to do it *old school* style and use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$admin = '/admin/';
if(substr($url, 0, strlen($admin)) === $admin) {
    Plugin::load('Josegonzalez/Upload');
    \Cake\Event\EventManager::instance()->on(new \App\Controller\Event\AppEventListener());
}
```

**Updated**

Your plugin should have it's own bootstrap file. Which contains

**Upload/config/bootstrap.php:**

```
\Cake\Event\EventManager::instance()->on(new \App\Controller\Event\AppEventListener());
```

The app's bootstrap then tells CakePHP to include the bootstrap when loading the plugin.

**App/config/bootstrap.php:**

```
    Plugin::load('Josegonzalez/Upload', ['bootstrap' => true]);
```

You shouldn't conditionally load your plugin.

I think you are searching for authentication on requests to your plugin. You want to limit use of your plugin only to authorized administrators. That is not a plugin issue. It is an authentication issue and you should be using the Authentication component in your plugin to verify the request is valid, and that the current user is an administrator.

Comment: thanks. is there anywhere else that i can load this event listener ( that i can use the cakephp's tool to do this ? it feels bad practice to use $_SERVER (this event is using  "Model.initialize"  btw)

Comment: No . i don't need auth for this plugin . my application contains 2 part . first one is admin web panel and second is the website for normal users. in admin panel i need uploading photo but i dont need it (upload plugin) in site home page. thats why i want to load this plugin for admin prefix. and the eventListener is handling the behaviors needed to load for admin panel ( like my custom timestamp and ..... ) . it is not really about access managment  i want it to load for my models only if i am in admin prefix ( because my models are the same for admin and main site)

Answer (score 1):

Quoting cakephp plugin docs https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html#plugin-routes

> You can also load plugin routes in your application’s routes list. Doing this provides you more control on how plugin routes are loaded and allows you to wrap plugin routes in additional scopes or prefixes.

So you can do

```
  Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {
       // Connect other routes.
        $routes->scope('/admin', function ($routes) {
        $routes->loadPlugin('Josegonzalez/Upload');
       });
       });
```

For your event listener,  load it inside plugin bootstrap configuration

```
    // inside plugin bootstra.php
    \Cake\Event\EventManager::instance()->on(new 
     \App\Controller\Event\AppEventListener());
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. I read that doc couple of times I don't know how I missed it. Can I load the event listener in the AdminAppController ( controller that all admin controllers are extending it) or something too ? (Considering it is "Model.initialize" event)

Comment: @hamidreza Yes, just put implement method `implementedEvents` as described [doc](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/events.html#registering-listeners)