# CakeDC's Forum plugin with a prefix

Tags: cakephp, routes, cakephp-3.0, cakedc

We're using CakePHP 3.5.17 and would like to use the forum plugin from CakeDC: https://github.com/CakeDC/cakephp-forum

We installed it with Composer, and added this line in the app's bootstrap.php :

```
Plugin::load('CakeDC/Forum', ['bootstrap' => true, 'routes' => true]);
```

The plugin works and we are able to navigate through the routes, using the path : "/forum", like "mysite.com/forum".

But we'd need to **use the plugin for a prefix** (let's say "member"), and then, it doesn't work anymore.
Navigating to "mysite.com/member/forum" throws an Missing Controller exception. CakePHP looks for a ForumController in the application, though it should look for the plugin...

We didn't write any particular routes for the prefix. Just declared it:

```
Router::prefix('member', function ($routes) {
    $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
});
```

Are we missing someting? I thought CakePHP's default routes were able to manage routes using a "/:prefix/:plugin/:controller" structure (according to the doc).

Here is what CakePHP traces:

```
params => [
    'controller' => 'Forum',
    'pass' => [],
    'action' => 'index',
    'prefix' => 'member',
    'plugin' => null,
    '_matchedRoute' => '/member/:controller',
    '_ext' => null,
    'isAjax' => false
]
```

Comment: not sure if is the same issue but maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47333733/cakephp3-load-plugin-for-special-prefix) answer could help.

Answer (score 0):

What out could do is load Forum plugin without routes

```
Plugin::load('CakeDC/Forum', ['bootstrap' => true]);
```

And the copy content of Forum plugin [routes.php](https://github.com/CakeDC/cakephp-forum/blob/master/config/routes.php) file to your app routes.php, only replacing `['path' => '/forum']` with `['path' => '/member/forum']`.

Comment: That'ok now, but still remains a problem: CakePHP is looking for a prefix folder in the plugin folder (pluginFolder/src/Controller/Membre/CategoriesController.php).

I don't want that! I don't want it to look for a prefix folder!
But how to prevent that?

Comment: Not sure if I understand you, but what if instead of declaring global prefix (`Router::prefix...`) you declare it in '/' scope (`$routes->prefix(...`)

Comment: Nop... the only workaround for me was to create prefix folders inside the plugin, extending the main controllers for every prefixed controller... and setting the path to render for every view... not perfect, but not too much duplicated files.